# Как из vb.net/c# создать новую windows-службу для стороннего приложения?

Tags: служба

Пишу приложение, которое должно уметь добавлять/удалять/редактировать windows-службы конкретной сторонней программы. Пользователь должен вбить кучу входных параметров строки запуска, а мое приложение уже склеивает все в правильном порядке и создает/модифицирует службу.
"Управляемое" приложение не .net, соответственно, стандартными методами через System.ServiceProcess.ServiceProcessInstaller управлять его службами нельзя.

Хочется сделать красиво, а не тупо через запуск sc c параметрами типа:

```
Dim newProc As Process = Process.Start("sc", "параметры для выполнения действия..")
newProc.WaitForExit()
```

Какие есть варианты?
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: В случае без .NET это делается вызовами к OpenSCManager, CreateService.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-RU/library/windows/desktop/ms684323(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо! То что надо :).
Ранее видел как используется управление службами (запуск, опрос статуса и остановка) через OpenSCManager, но метод CreateService как-то проглядел, поэтому и подумал, что создавать службы нельзя.